# Vertical button groups in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Looking to create a vertical button group that looks very similar to Twitters own button groups (example http://mobile-patterns.com/#/i/10)

I've tried changing Touch's code to `layout: 'vbox'` but it completely tweaks the roundness of each button and leaves their corner roundness as what they would look like in a horizontal format.

Code below:

```
var segmentedButton = new Ext.SegmentedButton({
    allowMultiple: true,
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [
        {
            text: 'Option 1'
        },
        {
            text   : 'Option 2',
            pressed: true
        },
        {
            text: 'Option 3'
        }
    ]
});
Ext.Viewport.add({ xtype: 'container', padding: 10, items: [segmentedButton] });
```

Do I need to add my own CSS styles in order to make it work? Or is there a built-in config?

I'm also wondering if it's best to use a `List` instead of a `SegmentedButton`...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thiem was right, I ended up using `container` to hold a group of buttons.

I was able to achieve the same effect by doing the following:

### Javascript

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    cls: 'btn-grouped ui-shadow ui-rd-soft ui-margin',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            docked: 'top',
            cls: 'btn btn-seg',
            text: 'Active relays'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            docked: 'top',
            cls: 'btn btn-seg',
            text: 'Relay history'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            docked: 'top',
            cls: 'btn btn-seg',
            text: 'About'
        }
    ]
}
```

### CSS

```
/**
 *  Buttons
 */
.btn-grouped {}
.btn-grouped .btn {background:#FFFFFF;color:#303030; border-color:#DEDEDE; border-bottom-width: 1px;border-top-width: 0px; text-shadow:none;}
.btn-grouped .btn .x-button-label {background:url(../img/btn-arrow-right.png) 97% 15% no-repeat;}
.btn-grouped .btn-seg {-webkit-border-radius:0px;border-radius:0px;}
.btn-grouped .btn-seg:first-child {-webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;}
.btn-grouped .btn-seg:last-child {-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;}

.btn {
padding: .6em 0;
font-size:110%;
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
}
.btn .x-button-label {text-align:left; padding-left:1em;}

/**
 *  Utilities
 */
.ui-shadow {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #858585;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #858585;
}
.ui-rd-soft {
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.ui-margin {
    margin:17px 0;
}
```

### Result

Here is an image of the final result!

[image: Vertical Button Group]

Comment: Thanks! Just realized I forgot to include `docked` so I'll put that in. I have a feeling it's important for cross-platform

Answer (score 1):

To easily create, customize and minimize conflicts with other components, you should define something as your buttons container like:

```
{
  xtype: 'container',
  items: [
    {xtype: 'button', text: '1', docked: 'top'},
    {xtype: 'button', text: '2', docked: 'top'},
    {xtype: 'button', text: '3', docked: 'top'},
  ]
}
```

The `docked` configs ensure that your buttons will not overlap the maximum height of your container.

The final thing is to add CSS properties to your container and inner buttons to "fake" it like a list with buttons. The easiest way as far as I know.

Note: You could remove `docked: 'top'` config and it still works ok. All of them depends on your CSS.

Comment: interesting, I didn't know docked had an impact. I'm actually going to post up an answer with the javascript/css I used to create a button group along with a screen shot. :)